# extjs 6 global store in packages

Tags: javascript, extjs, package, store, extjs6

I'm using extjs 6 and I need to create a global store for a package. I usually create global stores for my application in

```
app/store/mystore.js
```

and then register in Application.js

```
stores:[
    'mystore'
]
```

I have tried to create it in

```
packages/mypkg/src/store/mypkgstore.js
```

but it doesn't work... When application runs, mypkgstore.js is not downloaded.

Should I add it in any file as global stores for application?

I have tried adding it in required clause in other class and the file is downloaded but the store doesn't load data...

Answer (score 0):

Define the store in Application.js as below:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

name: 'MyApp',

stores: [
    // TODO: add global / shared stores here
    'mystore'
]  
});
```

In the mypkgstore.js, ensure you specify it as:

```
Ext.define('APP.store.MyPkgStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.mystore',
storeId: 'MyPkgStore'
});
```

Comment: but doing that, the package is not an independent package. I try to create a module and use it in differents applications so I cannot define it in Application.js because you have to change the code in every application that uses the package

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this help at this moment. Any way... as you may know, packages does not have any init file like Application.js, in this case, you need to instantiate manually each store. In my case I did:

Main View:

```
Ext.define('Activities.view.Activities', {
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
   xtype: 'activities',

   requires: [
       'Activities.store.Activities'
   ],
   store: Ext.create('Activities.store.Activities'),

   columns: [...]
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('Activities.store.Activities', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   alias: 'store.activities',
   storeId: 'activities',
});
```

Or if you have many stores, you can instanciate them all in the init() method of the viewController of the main view, something like:

```
Ext.define('Activities.view.ActivitiesController', {

   extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
   alias: 'controller.activities',
   id: 'activities',

   requires: [
       'Activities.store.Activities',
       'Activities.store.Countries',

       ...
   ],

   /**
    * Called when the view is created
    */
   init: function (view) {
       Ext.create('Activities.store.Activities');
       Ext.create('Activities.store.Countries');

       ...
   }

});
```

I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: It isn't a bad idea but you need always a main screen to load it. In my case i have an application who works as a container and then i have some packages working inside the main aplication, the problem is the main screen is in main application and package load new different screens so i don't have a main screen in the package. maybe i can do it in app.js of each package. thanks!!

Comment: thinking about it, the packages don't have any app.js. I think the best solution is load a generic class when i load the package screens and create the stores only if they are not created. i will tell you if it works. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is by just creating a ViewModel using the concept of MVVM

Your View Where you declared a Grid to :

```
Ext.define('YourProject.View',{
requires : ['YourProject.Controller','YourProject.ViewModel'],
extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
controller : 'MyController',
viewModel : 'MyViewModel',

initComponent : function(){
var me = this;
    Ext.apply(me,{

    xtype : 'grid',
    itemId : 'myGrid',
    });
};

});
```

Example of Store in ViewModel:

```
Ext.define('YourProject.ViewModel',{
extend : 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias : 'MyViewModel',

//declare you stores here

stores : {
   myStore : {
    autoLoad : true,
    fields : [{name : 'id', type : 'string'},
              {name : 'value', type : 'string'}],
    proxy : {
    url  : 'you/actionHere.do',
    extraParams : {
      yourParameter1 = 'paramVal',
      yourParameter2 = 'paramVal2'
      },
      reader : {
         type : 'json',
         rootProperty : 'data',
         totalPropert : 'total'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

});

Use the Store in Controller :

```
Ext.define('YourProject.Controller',{
extend : 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias : 'myController',

applyState : function(){

var me = this;

//Get you store from ViewModel by doing this
var store = me.getView().getViewModel().getStore('dmlshFeeAmt');
me.getView().down(#'myGrid').setStore(store);

}
});
```

Hope this can help your project :)

Comment: doing that you only can use the store in that context. If you need to use it in another component with its own viewmodel, you can not access. It is a good solution for only one screen but for a package is not valid. Thanks!

Comment: Well the concept of MVVM is one ViewModel is to one View. I had worked with massive projects with extjs and I never had an experience accessing multiple stores in a singular .js. Goodluck tho